# How did you mention a string(chain) properly

Tags: strings

I am writing my thesis, in my document I have several paragraphs that mention character chains, How did you mention a string(chain) properly?, for example:

```
Si termina con $G$ no puede
Si termina con 'G' no puede
Si termina con "G" no puede
```

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the kind of document? Typically `$G$` is used for math expressions. You can might want to use one of `\textit{}`, `\textbf{}` or `\texttt{}`. Then define some sort of definition for your document that a reader knows that a string is always italic (for example `\textit{your string}`)

Comment: If different chains need to be juxtaposed (for example DNA strings), then a monospaced font like `\texttt` makes the best sense.

Comment: you can put your answer please, for the other readers

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes you can put your answer please, for the other readers

Comment: @faltfe you can put your answer please, for the other readers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a stylistic issue

Answer (score 4):

If strings have to be juxtaposed, one string against another, as in the case of DNA, a monospaced font makes sense, to avoid misalignments that can arise both from letter width differences as well as kerning.

Here, I show the same 2 strings juxtaposed in `rm` and `tt` fonts.  Even though the top and bottom of the two strings contain the **exact same** letters and in the same quantity, letter kerning alone causes the roman strings to be mismatched.  The problem is avided with `tt`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\begin{document}
\stackunder{ATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGC}{TACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACG}\bigskip

\ttfamily
\stackunder{ATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGCATGC}{TACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACGTACG}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion there isn't really a proper way or a best practice how to write a string chain. It is more important that the reader of your document know what a string format mean. This means that *one* should define its own string formatting for a document and explain their meanings.

In your question you wrote `$G$`. This would typically be a math constant. I would not use quotation marks either because then you don't know if it is a quote or a string chain.

Here is how I would handle your approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ducks}

\newcommand{\technical}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\coding}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newcommand{\fancy}[1]{%
    \tikz{\duck}%
    ~#1~%
    \tikz{\duck}%
}

\begin{document}

    \section*{String formatting definitions}

        \begin{itemize}
            \item Technical string are formatted bold in document. Example: \technical{TeX.SX}
            \item All DNA Coding is done in monospace \coding{ATGC}
            \item \fancy{I'm a fancy duck string}
        \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

This approach have two advantages:

- The reader can look up the meaning of a string format
- You can simply redefine a string format for the whole document easily